# How to view detailed Script errors instead of in IE

Tags: javascript

When there is a Javascript error in IE I get an 'Errors on this page may not work correctly' by clicking the tray in the bottom left corner.  I've used Firebug and couldn't find anything that could do it yet.  Maybe i'm missing something, or is there anything else that offers the same type of functionality of IE script errors, but instead of showing the just the error line #, it will also possibly show a snipped of the code or elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Older versions of IE are utter garbage, especially for error messages. Upgrade to IE9, it's got a decent set of developer tools.

Comment: currently upgrading.. lets c.. =]

Comment: The problem usually is one of the following. Missing the var keyword in front of a variable declaration, having a trailing , at the end of an array/object literal, or missing a ;. The line number internet explorer gives normally isn't correct either in old versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox/Firebug, you can right-click on an element in your browser page and select Inspect Element with Firebug.  Once Firebug is open, click on the Console tab.  In the console tab, you can choose what kind of errors you want to see.  Javascript errors will show with either "All" or "Errors" selected.

It will show you the line number of the error, the error message and give you a link you can click on to open that part of the javascript source so you can see exactly where the error occurred.

There are some types of parse errors where the error is discovered many lines after the cause so the extra line it points to is not always correct.  For javascript execution errors, the exact line should always be correct.

The newer versions of IE have something similar builtin.  If you press F12, the IE debug console window opens and you can see similar information there.

Chrome and Safari also have a debugger and error console built in.

Comment: Which version of FireBug? Lite or Standard?  I don't see the 'errors' tab in the lite version.

Comment: +1 for IE9's developer toolbar. It's still awful compared to Firebug and the WebKit Inspector, but it's a far cry better than anything for IE<8.

Comment: @ZeeTee - My comments about Firebug are all about full Firebug, not Firebug Lite.  The one time I tried Firebug Lite, I didn't not find it useful.